# Как настроить автообновление информации в боте с парсеров

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот, heroku

Есть бот под ВК, написанный на Python, размещён на хостинг Heroku. Также на тот же сервер размещены несколько парсеров с разных сайтов, но присутствует небольшая проблема, когда на сайтах информация обновляется, в боте этого не происходит автоматически, только при перезапуска бота вручную.
Вопрос: как сделать, чтобы информация автоматически обновлялась и доходила до бота?
Пример парсера(ruble_course.py):

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

r_usd = req.get('https://finance.rambler.ru/calculators/converter/1-USD-RUB/')
html_usd = BS(r_usd.content, 'html.parser')

value_usd = html_usd.select('.converter-display__value')
dif_usd = html_usd.select('.converter-change-table__change')
```

Использование в боте:

```
import ruble_course_parser as rcp
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

#login to system as club bot
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='тут токен')
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, group_id)

#to get methods
vk = vk_session.get_api()

#ruble course message send
rcp_message = 'Курс рубля: \n 1 доллар = {0} рублей\n Изменение: {1}'.format(rcp.usd_course, rcp.usd_course_dif)

def main():

    for event in longpoll.listen():

        #if new message was got
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            message = event.obj['message']
            user = message['from_id']
            text = message['text']

            if text == 'Узнать курс рубля':
                vk.messages.send(peer_id=user,\
                     message=rcp_message,random_id = 0)

#run mainloop
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `в боте этого не происходит автоматически` как вы сделали логику, так она и работает. Добавьте, например, таймер (`threading.Timer`) по которому в боте обновляете инфу. А так, вопросу нужна конкретизация добавьте в вопрос пример кода в котором бот получает инфу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо, кто хотел ответить. Я нашел ответ (https://qna.habr.com/q/520860), для будущих поколений.

Раз вариант:

```
import sched, time

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def f():
    s.enter(5, 1, f)  # Перезапуск через 5 секунд
    print(time.time())

f()
s.run()
```

Два вариант:

```
import threading

def f():
  threading.Timer(5.0, f).start()  # Перезапуск через 5 секунд
  print("Hello!")

f()
```

Совсем тупой вариант:

```
import time

def f():
  print("Hello!")

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    f()
```